List Validation between different Sharepoints - Not refreshing on web
I have FileA and FileB, two sharepoints.
On FileB i have the list validation criteria (from 1 to 10), on FileA i have to implement the list validation picking from the list of FileB.
I tried with a Power Query to get the data from FileB and it works, but it doesn't refresh when using the web version on Sharepoint, so it's not really useful.
Is there any other trick to do so?

Do you want to copy list "validation formula" from one SharePoint site to another SharePoint site? Can you add more details to your question (Screenshots might help, if any)?
